# Appending to JTextArea is not creating a line break on '\n'

Tags: java, text, character-encoding

I'm loading string resources from a text file (so as to not have to rebuild if I need to change them) which when appended to the JTextArea displays as "Some sentence,\n on the same line."

When I hard code the exact same String, it appends fine.
Where could this be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your text file look like? If "\n" is in the text file it's probably copied literally, i.e. it's not treated as an escape sequence.

EDIT: You could try reading the text file as a property file and automatically have e.g. \n parsed a newline.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
p.load(fileStream);    
String value = p.getProperty(key);
```

Comment: One per line, eg. `roll : You have rolled a score of %d.\nWhat would you like to do now?`

Comment: And I add the left word as a key to the map, and the content after `: ` as the value.

Comment: So you have "\n" in the text file, right? That's probably why it doesn't work. In this case you'll have to do a string replacement of "\\n" to "\n" after you have read the string. I suggest you try using property files instead. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In the text file do this...

**"1st_Half_of_String"**`+"\n"+`**"2nd_Half_of_String"**